# How to refer css class in a component.ts file

Tags: css, angular, d3.js, graph

I am trying to create a neural net visualization using d3.js in Angular 7. I have successfully created the nodes but the links are not appearing. The code refers to a css class defined in the components css file. What am I doing wrong?

Shown below is the code responsible for link creation:

```
// draw links
    var link:any = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return nodes[d.source].x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return nodes[d.source].y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return nodes[d.target].x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return nodes[d.target].y; })
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
```

**css :**

```
.link {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

shown below is the code of my complete **neural.component.ts** file (which contains the above typescript code).

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import {select,schemeCategory10,scaleOrdinal} from 'd3';
import { angularMath } from 'angular-ts-math';
declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-neuralcanvas',
  templateUrl: './neuralcanvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./neuralcanvas.component.css']
})
export class NeuralcanvasComponent implements OnInit {

    // color = scaleOrdinal().range(schemeCategory10)
  inputLayerHeight = 4;
  outputLayerHeight=5;
  hiddenLayersDepths =[3,4];
  hiddenLayersCount =2;
    nodeSize = 17;
  width :any = 500 ;
  height = 400;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.draw()
  }

  draw() {
        console.log('in draw')
        if (!select("svg")[0]) {
        } else {
            //clear d3
            select('svg').remove();
        }
        var svg = select("#neuralNet").append("svg")
        .attr("width", this.width)
        .attr("height", this.height);

        var networkGraph : any = this.buildNodeGraph();
        //buildNodeGraph();
        this.drawGraph(networkGraph, svg);
    }


    buildNodeGraph() {
        var newGraph:any = {
            "nodes": []
        };

        //construct input layer
        var newFirstLayer: any = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.inputLayerHeight; i++) {
            var newTempLayer1 :any = {"label": "i"+i, "layer": 1};
            newFirstLayer.push(newTempLayer1);
        }

        //construct hidden layers
        var hiddenLayers:any = [];
        for (var hiddenLayerLoop = 0; hiddenLayerLoop < this.hiddenLayersCount; hiddenLayerLoop++) {
            var newHiddenLayer:any = [];
            //for the height of this hidden layer
            for (var i = 0; i < this.hiddenLayersDepths[hiddenLayerLoop]; i++) {
                var newTempLayer2:any = {"label": "h"+ hiddenLayerLoop + i, "layer": (hiddenLayerLoop+2)};
                newHiddenLayer.push(newTempLayer2);
            }
            hiddenLayers.push(newHiddenLayer);
        }

        //construct output layer
        var newOutputLayer:any = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.outputLayerHeight; i++) {
            var newTempLayer3 = {"label": "o"+i, "layer": this.hiddenLayersCount + 2};
            newOutputLayer.push(newTempLayer3);
        }

        //add to newGraph
        var allMiddle:any = newGraph.nodes.concat.apply([], hiddenLayers);
        newGraph.nodes = newGraph.nodes.concat(newFirstLayer, allMiddle, newOutputLayer );

        return newGraph;
    }

    drawGraph(networkGraph, svg) {
        var color = scaleOrdinal(schemeCategory10);
        var graph = networkGraph;
        var nodes = graph.nodes;

        // get network size
        var netsize = {};
        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
            if(d.layer in netsize) {
                netsize[d.layer] += 1;
            } else {
                netsize[d.layer] = 1;
            }
            d["lidx"] = netsize[d.layer];
        });

        // calc distances between nodes
        var largestLayerSize = Math.max.apply(
            null, Object.keys(netsize).map(function (i) { return netsize[i]; }));

        var xdist = this.width / Object.keys(netsize).length,
            ydist = (this.height-15) / largestLayerSize;

        // create node locations
        nodes.map(function(d) {
            d["x"] = (d.layer - 0.5) * xdist;
            d["y"] = ( ( (d.lidx - 0.5) + ((largestLayerSize - netsize[d.layer]) /2 ) ) * ydist )+10 ;
        });

        // autogenerate links
        var links:any = [];
        nodes.map(function(d, i) {
            for (var n in nodes) {
                if (d.layer + 1 == nodes[n].layer) {
                    links.push({"source": parseInt(i), "target": parseInt(n), "value": 1}) }
            }
        }).filter(function(d) { return typeof d !== "undefined"; });


        // draw links
        var link:any = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return nodes[d.source].x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return nodes[d.source].y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return nodes[d.target].x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return nodes[d.target].y; })
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) {return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

        // draw nodes
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; }
        );

        var circle = node.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", this.nodeSize)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.layer); });



        node.append("text")
        .attr("dx", "-.35em")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("font-size", ".6em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
    }
}
```

the code of the **neural.component.css**:

```
.link {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

The current output lokks like this:

[image]

I want to show the inks as:
[image]

As you'll see the generation code is already there I want to know how to refer the class to get the links appearing in Angular 7

Comment: If everything else is good, try `style.css` at the root. Paste your `css` there.

Comment: Did you try with style.css?

Comment: @AnuradhaMudalige  what do you mean by root?

Comment: @Suleka_28 inside `src` folder at the top level of your project there is a file named as `style.css` where global style are defined. Try that out.